# Suprema and Infima of a Set

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set below bounded from above or below? Find the sup & inf if so. Justify whether the sup or inf is a max or min.

$$S_1=[0,1)$$
$$S_2=\Big\{\frac{a^2} {1+a^2}\Big|\,a>0\Big\}$$
$$S_3=\Big\{\frac{a^4} {1+a^2}\Big|\,a>0\Big\}$$

$S_1$ is bounded from below and above; any negative number is a lower bound and 1 is the upper bound. 1 is the sup and 0 is the inf.

$S_2$ is bounded from below because $\frac {1} {1/a^2+1}$ approaches 0 as a approaches infinity and $\frac {1} {1/a^2+1}$ approaches infinity as a approaches 0.

$S_3$ is unbounded because $\frac {1} {1/a^4+1/a^2}$ is undefined as a approaches infinity and approaches infinity as a approaches 0.

Not sure how to "Justify whether the sup or inf is a max or min." and whether my answer above is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Infimum of $S_1$ belongs to the set so infimum is same as minimum. Supremum does not belong to the set, so supremum is not maximum. There is no maximum in $S_1$.

For $S_2$ infimum is $0$ but $0$ does not belong to $S_2$. Supremum is $1$ and this is also not in the set.

$S_3$ is not bounded above. It is bounded below by $0$ and this infimum is not a minimum.

Comment: how would i justify it?

Comment: @jamesblack For which part of the answer you are asking for justification?

Comment: since the question asks justify whether the sup or inf is a max or min, do i simply claim it is a max/min or is there a way of justirfying it?

Comment: @jamesblack If the supremum of a set belongs to the set the it is the maximum.  Otherwise there is no maximum. For example, the supremum of $S_1$ is $1$ but it is not a maximum since $ 1\notin S_1$.